# ActionLink Includes Current {id} in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

The page currently displayed in my browser is: `http://localhost:19255/Object/Browse/1`.

A link on this page is created with: `@Html.ActionLink("...", "Browse", "Object")`

But the generated link is actually: `/Object/Browse/1`

My understanding of what's happening is that MVC sees my route has an {id} portion, which I did not supply. So it went ahead and included the {id} portion from the current page.

Fair enough, but how do I create a link without it? I tried `null`, and `new { id = null }` but neither worked.

Comment: So you want an action link with no param, is that what I hear?

Comment: Without seeing the action that creates `/Object/Browse` view I'm not sure how you could not see the `id` because it looks like that View requires a value to render the view to view the object with that `id`. Does that make sense? lol

Comment: I would like see your default Route...

Comment: We have not made any changes to the route created automatically when we built our MVC application. It's completely standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While neither of the following work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("...", "Browse", "Object", null)              // Has no effect
@Html.ActionLink("...", "Browse", "Object", new { id = null }) // Error
```

The following solves the issue:

```
@Html.ActionLink("...", "Browse", "Object", new { id = "" })   // No ID is passed
```

Comment: If you'd like to dig into why, the ASP.NET MVC source is available here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781

Answer (score 0):

I believe MVC is pulling this Id from the Model directly since you don't specify it. I've seen this before but I don't have time at the moment to verify it.

Try overwriting `@Model.Id` before rendering that link to see if that's where it's coming from. Then, I think, you'd be able to stash the Id value off in a new variable in case you need it and set @Model.Id = null. Kind of a hack... of course :)

Comment: My Model has no `Id` member. It must be getting it from the view itself somehow.