# ID added to ActionLink improperly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

This is in `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            @Html.ActionLink(Resource.CompanyDetails, "Details", "Company")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can notice, no ID added or anything... For some reason, if I'm at an employee's or work station, or whatever else's details page, the ID of the entity I'm viewing is added to the ActionLink above.

Any idea why?

**EDIT:**

Tried to overwrite the id as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955466/actionlink-includes-current-id-in-url), but no luck. Also, I'm using attribute routing

**EDIT2:** This is how the routing is set up for the whole controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("Company")]
[Route("{action}/{id:guid?}")]
```

**EDIT3:**

Since I only need not to have the ID in the URL in one place, I hard coded the URL, not the best solution, but it'll work till I find a solution

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481285/mvc-actionlink-remembers-id-field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481285/mvc-actionlink-remembers-id-field)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried that and it didn't work. That question is probably for an older version of MVC.

Comment: can you post the attr routing you set for this action?

Comment: I've traced through the MVC source to `UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(string,string,string,RouteValueDictionary,RouteCollection, RequestContext, bool)`.  Looks like your ID is getting merged in the call to `MergeRouteValues` about halfway into the function.  I don't see another merge call between that and the creation of the link.

Comment: Any idea on how to try not to make it merge?

Comment: I have two possible solutions which are little more than hacks.  1) remove the ID from the route values, generate the link, then add the ID back.  2) write your own Html helper which generates the link correctly.

Comment: No idea how to do no1 and have a look at edit3 on why not no2 :)